# How to query and plot the time difference between single measurements?

Tags: timestamp, grafana, influxdb

I have a time series of data from a specific sensor, which has a sample rate of 16khz. Since I am noticing that my data in InfluxDB is kind of irregular (has sometimes time frames of 80 - 500ms with no data), I am looking for a proper way to query and plot the time differences between each single entry of a measurement. Is this even possible? I came across a query similar to this one

```
SELECT elapsed('value', 1ms) FROM "measurement" WHERE value > 1
```

But as a result I am just receiving all timestamps. Is there another possibility without creating an script or something like that to get the time differences for consecutive entries?

Answer (score 0):

I would run another query to find problems in the data:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM "measurement"
WHERE <time condition>
GROUP BY time(1s)
```

I would expect count 16k for every second if you have 16kHz sample rate. You can go even lower with time aggregation to have better granularity (e.g. 1ms)

Comment: What exactly would you put into the time condition? I mean I don't have fixed timestamps and there is no extra field for them.

Comment: @FredFloete Absolute or relative time https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#time-syntax